# Why does my button overflow the container in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, viewport-units

I have set a div to size `78vh`. 78/13 = 6 For each button, I did a size `6vh` so all 13 of them should fit within `78vh`. In Firefox, everything looks nice, however in Google Chrome the last button goes beyond. Does anyone know why? Please note I am not an HTML developer, so a simple explanation would mean a lot to me.

```
<body>
    <div style="height:85vh;overflow:auto;background-color:green;margin-top:10vh;">
        <div style="height:78vh;margin:2vh;background-color:white;">
            <div class="visible-sm-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block" style="background-color:yellow;height:78vh;margin-right:66%;">
                    <button style="height:6vh; width:12vh"> 0 </button>
                    <br><button style="height:6vh; width:12vh"> 0 </button>  
                    <br><button style="height:6vh; width:12vh"> 0 </button>
                    <br><button style="height:6vh; width:12vh"> 0 </button>
                    <br><button style="height:6vh; width:12vh"> 0 </button>
                    <br><button style="height:6vh; width:12vh"> 0 </button>
                    <br><button style="height:6vh; width:12vh"> 0 </button>
                    <br><button style="height:6vh; width:12vh"> 0 </button>
                    <br><button style="height:6vh; width:12vh"> 0 </button>
                    <br><button style="height:6vh; width:12vh"> 0 </button>
                    <br><button style="height:6vh; width:12vh"> 0 </button>
                    <br><button style="height:6vh; width:12vh"> 0 </button>
                    <br><button style="height:6vh; width:12vh"> 0 </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: Why you do not let your buttons expand parent instead of specifying parent height? Also check if your `<br>` does not add additional spaces

Comment: Hm, may I ask how do I do that? It's funny, because it works just as I want in firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `<br>` tags and add 'display:block;' style for buttons.

Answer (score 1):

This is down to the `<br />` tags between the buttons. It appears that, in Chrome at least, the `<br />` tag is changing height in steps as the height of the window changes. This makes the combined height of the buttons look either too little or too much.

A way of getting around this would be to remove the `<br />` tags and set the CSS display property of the buttons to `block`.

This Fiddle shows the difference between the two approaches: https://jsfiddle.net/0f5y1vj8/. The method with the `<br />` tags is on the right. Try changing the height of the result pane and you'll see how the spacing between the buttons changes.